# How to curve image in differnt shape, just like 'm'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to give curve to image just as shirt collar.
[Curve image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqCy6.png)

I have image.[Main image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MaPz.png)

I use below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function allcurve(event){   
    topcolrcurve(event);    
}

function topcolrcurve(event){   

    var getImagePath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        console.log(getImagePath)

    temp_can1 = document.getElementById('f6258182013');
    temp_can1_ctx = temp_can1.getContext('2d');

    topcolrrotator(getImagePath, '-100');
}

function topcolrrotator(var2, var3) 
{
    var mr_rotator_var = document.getElementById('colrtop_can');
    var mr_rotator_var_ctx = mr_rotator_var.getContext("2d");
    mr_rotator_var.width = mr_rotator_var.width;
    var imageObj_rotator3 = new Image();
    var hpp='';
    imageObj_rotator3.onload = function () {
        var pattern_rotator3 = mr_rotator_var_ctx.createPattern(imageObj_rotator3, "repeat");
        mr_rotator_var_ctx.fillStyle = pattern_rotator3;
        mr_rotator_var_ctx.rect(0, 0, mr_rotator_var.width, mr_rotator_var.height);
        mr_rotator_var_ctx.rotate(var3 * Math.PI / 180);
        mr_rotator_var_ctx.fill();
        hpp = mr_rotator_var.toDataURL('image/png');
        rightcufover(hpp);
    };
   imageObj_rotator3.src = var2;
}

function rightcufover(event)
{
    var getImagePath = event;
    var ctx = e.getContext("2d"); 

    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = slice;
    img.src = getImagePath;

        function slice() {
        var w = e.width = this.width;
        var h = e.height = this.height;
        var step = Math.PI * 1 / w;           
        var scale = -100;                       

            for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            ctx.drawImage(this,
            x, 0, 1, h,                       
            x, Math.sin(step*x)*scale, 1, h); 
            }
            var hp=e.toDataURL('image/png');
            $('#collrtop').attr("value", hp);
        }
}
```

Please help how to curve image.

I try it in different way but it not show proper, also I have to maintain quality of image.

Comment: You should try svg for this purpose.

Comment: Please provide sample code if you have, @AsifSharifShahid, I did't get proper result

Comment: [Simple Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/by9z81e1/1/)